MetricsPackageUI.dll missing from Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 installation
I just installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 with default settings. After launching it for the first time, it proceeded upto theme selection and then showed the following error.
Error Image
After running devenv.exe /log and examining the log file at %APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_f0a31881\ActivityLog.xml I found that MetricsPackageUI.dll was missing from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies folder. I tried both repairing and reinstalling visual studio but the error persisted. Please provide a solution to this problem.
EDIT:
The problem was resolved by downgrading to Visual Studio 2022 LTSC 17.6. Downgrading instructions are mentioned in this post. The one that worked for me was Jodie's answer from that post.

I’m voting to close this question because “The problem was resolved by downgrading to Visual Studio 2022 LTSC 17.6”
